# How to set USB Tethering automatically when plugged in (Android 8.1)

Tags: android, shell, reflection, tether

I'm going to create a background service (or whatever else) to enable USB tethering to share 4G internet on my pc automatically when the phone is plugged in.

I have an [OP5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnePlus#OnePlus_5) (Android 8.1) with root.

I tried Automate app, but it doesn't work (getting an exception when the task try to enable tether USB)

I tried to call `setUsbTethering` by reflection, I got an `InvocationTargetException` due to *MANAGE_USB* permission, I tried to grant this permission, but it seems that require to enumerate devices and when I try to get devices using `getDeviceList` the result is empty.

The last thing, after some research some people did the trick by shell command like

```
service call connectivity CODE i32 1
```

but the code seems to be different according to version (`30, 32 or 33`) from the internal [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) file.

So, I finally decided to ask for some help since I don't have any pieces of knowledge about Android core and advanced things, any suggestion or help to achieve this will be appreciated.